# Angular: assign and access promise via rootScope

Tags: angularjs

I would like to use a promise and access it through a rootScope instead of using return statement. The problem I am having is that promise is getting resolved before my resolve finishes. In the code below, successFunction in my ajax call is getting executed before my defer.resolve() is completed. Is there anyway I can get my successFunction to wait until after my defer.resolve in app-directive gets completed? Here is my code:

app-directive.js

```
function(app) {
    app.directive('spinner', function ($uibModal, $timeout, $q) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        template: [
            '<div style="display:none;" class="modal-dialog">',
            '<div class="modal-header ng-scope" style="text-align: center;">',
            '   {{spinnerMessage}}',
            '</div>',
            '<div class="modal-body ng-scope">',
            '   <img class="spinner-image" ng-src="../../Content/img/spinner.gif" />',
            '</div>',
            '</div>'
        ].join(''),
        link: function (scope, element) {
            scope.$watch(function () {
                return scope.$root.loadMask
            }, function () {
                 if (scope.$root.loadMask == true) {
                    scope.spinnerModal = $uibModal.open({
                        template: element[0].innerHTML,
                        size: 'sm',
                        backdrop: 'static',
                        keyboard: 'false'
                    });
                 }
                 else {
                    var defer = $q.defer();
                    $timeout(function () {
                        defer.resolve(scope.spinnerModal.close())
                    }, 3000);

                    scope.$root.spinnerClosed = defer.promise;
                 }
            }, true);
}
```

ajaxService.js

```
app.register.service('ajaxService', ['$http', '$rootScope', function ($http, $rootScope) {
    this.AddUser = function (user, successFunction, errorFunction) {
        // Initialization
        $rootScope.loadMask = true;

        $http.post('Account/AddUser', user)
        .success(function (response, status, headers, config) {
            $rootScope.loadMask = false;
            $rootScope.spinnerClosed.then(function (result) {
                successFunction(response, status);
            });
        })
        .error(function (response, status) {
            $rootScope.loadMask = false;
            $rootScope.spinnerClosed.then(function (result) {
                errorFunction(response, status);
            });
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. AngularJS has a .then method that you use which is a basically a callback function.

```
 $http.post('Account/AddUser', user)
     .then(
            function successCallback(response) {
                $rootScope.loadMask = false;
                successFunction(response, status);
            },
            function failureCallback(response) {
                $rootScope.loadMask = false;
                errorFunction(response, status)
            }
      );
```

Answer (score 0):

AngularJS executes listener functions as soon as the watcher is registered, so your `spinnerClosed` promise is probably already resolve when `this.AddUser` is called on your service.

You can insert an additional check to see if the listener is called as a part of initialization.

> After a watcher is registered with the scope, the listener fn is called asynchronously (via $evalAsync) to initialize the watcher. In rare cases, this is undesirable because the listener is called when the result of watchExpression didn't change. To detect this scenario within the listener fn, you can compare the newVal and oldVal. If these two values are identical (===) then the listener was called due to initialization.

[Angular JS API Reference / $rootScope.Scope](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope)